# autolayout center X constraints flips in RTL in iOS 9

Tags: ios, autolayout, ios9

I have 2 buttons in a view and following is the screen for RTL works fine:

[image]

And in RTL it flips both and shows like this :

[image]

I am unable to stop flipping by unchecking respect language direction

[image]

I have added Constraint like this :

[image: [English Button]
[image: [Arabic Button]

Its working fine on iOS 8 I want to stop them automatic flipping for iOS 9, Any guidance ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the semantic content attribute of the superview to Force Left-To-Right.

[image: Setting the SCA of a view]

Answer (score -1):

or You can use this in appDelegate,

```
-(BOOL) isGreaterIOSVersion:(NSString*) version
{
    NSString *systemVersion = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];
    if ([systemVersion compare:version options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending) {
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

add below code to in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions function

```
if([self isGreaterIOSVersion:9.0]) {
        [[UIView appearance] setSemanticContentAttribute:UISemanticContentAttributeForceLeftToRight];
    }
```

it will remove RTL

Comment: Already used that, the error is generating after that code :)

Comment: Please don't do this. Setting ```semanticContentAttribute``` on ```UIView```'s ```appearance``` proxy is not supported and will not do the right thing in most cases.